# Regex leading zeros from string in Hive

Tags: regex, hive

I have a 19 - character string in `Hive` that I need to split up and remove any leading zeros.

**Example**:

```
7212092180052740029
```

I need it to be split like this

```
721 20 9218 00527 40029
```

So there are no leading zeros in 1st, 2nd, or 3rd section, and `00` would be removed from the 4th section;  section 5 will be disregarded.  My desired result would be

```
721209218527
```

My first-pass solution is

```
trim(concat_ws('', regexp_replace(substr(some_string, 1, 3),  '^0*', '')
                 , regexp_replace(substr(some_string, 4, 2),  '^0*', '')
                 , regexp_replace(substr(some_string, 6, 4),  '^0*', '')
                 , regexp_replace(substr(some_string, 10, 5), '^0*', '')))
```

but this seems like extreme overkill.  Any ideas how to do this with one line of regex?

Also, it should be noted that in any of the 5 sections, when split, will never be all zeros (i.e. section one will never be `000`); if so then my 'solution' wouldn't work, as *all* zeros would be leading ones and `'^0*` would return nothing.

Comment: what is the logic of split

Comment: I figured that would be pretty apparent from the question.  (3, 2, 4, 5, 5)

Comment: I can't check it right now, but have you tried not using regex?
Maybe for removing lead zeros, cast the splitted string to int and then back to string will work for you and will be faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^0*|(?<=^.{3})0*|(?<=^.{5})0*|(?<=^.{9})0*|(?<=^.{14}).*$
```

You can use this regex and replace by `empty string`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/rO0yD8/15